# Looking for a way to exclude frontpage and nav menu from query filter

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, pre-get-posts

maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way, but I need to:
A) exclude posts in queries site-wide (minus frontpage and navbar) based on a comparison with a meta_value, and
B) orderby a differnt meta_value_num, then title

this works:

```
function my_get_posts( $query ) {
    $today = current_time( 'timestamp', 0 );
    if ( ! is_admin() && ! is_home() && ! $query->is_page('Locations')) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'wpcf-post-weight' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-news-expire-date',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
```

But, since `pre_get_posts` can not use `is_front_page()` as a conditional, I'm a little stuck about how to exclude the front page. Would changing the hook to `parse_query`, then using `is_front_page()` be the way to go?

Also, I notice that the pages this function gets called on no longer have the nav menu generated by Appearance>Menus. I can only assume this is because the menu is generated with a query. I have no idea how to exclude the nav query in particular.

**EDIT:** Just noticed this seems to work on every page but the frontpage to exclude the nav menu `$query->query_vars['post_type'] != 'nav_menu_item'` Would there be any reason that the function has access to the query_vars being passed to WP_Query on every page except the front page? Only frontpage is throwing this error:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: WP_Query::$post in <b>...wp-includes/query.php</b> on line <b>3034</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>...wp-includes/query.php</b> on line <b>3402</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>...wp-includes/query.php</b> on line <b>3404</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>...wp-includes/query.php</b> on line <b>3406</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: WP_Query::$post in <b>...wp-includes/query.php</b> on line <b>3034</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>...wp-includes/query.php</b> on line <b>3402</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>...wp-includes/query.php</b> on line <b>3404</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>...wp-includes/query.php</b> on line <b>3406</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: post_type in <b>...lib/custom.php</b> on line <b>1051</b>
```

and lastly,...sadly,...`is_main_query()` just won't work. (we found ourselves in some sticky situations that required some secondary queries.)

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `WP_Query` does have `is_front_page()` method, why do you reason it cannot be used?

Comment: primarily because it doesn't seem to be working when i add it as a conditional, and secondarily, because [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#A_Warning_About_Conditional_Functions) states that because pre_get_posts runs before WP_Query, is_front_page() is not available.

Comment: According with the `preg_get_posts()` documentation, `is_front_page()` won't work in the `pre_get_posts()` action hook. `is_home()` will do.

Comment: @cybnet unfortunately have a static frontpage as opposed to home.

Comment: @sosukeinu I just saw that you both was talking about `is_front_page()` and I wanted to clarify this aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this to work to exclude the frontpage `!$query->get( 'page_id' ) == get_option( 'page_on_front' )` thanks to [this](http://www.wpaustralia.org/wordpress-forums/topic/pre_get_posts-and-is_front_page/#post-989)

seems kind of "hack-y," but it works.

to exclude the nav-menu query `$query->query_vars['post_type'] != 'nav_menu_item'`

Thank you everyone for your help.